# Pageview Slide , I can't insert the image into the top and change the size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I would like to perform a pageview slide but when I try to insert the images inside the container they are in the center and I can not put them on top or even I can resize the images when I put in the pageview , someone would have an example or hicsun for this problem

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp
     (

       home:Scaffold(
         body: Column(
           children: [
             Expanded(
               child: PageView(
                 children: [

                   Image(image:AssetImage('assets/tic.png'))
                 ],

                 ),
             )
           ], 
         )     
       )
       )
       
     ;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Share your code, so i can find and solve the problem. without code !!!

Comment: YES, I put the code , thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can use a widget under the `PageView`

```
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: PageView(
                children: const [
                  FlutterLogo(
                    size: 10,
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.purple,
                child: Text('Salam'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

you can use `flex` to adjust the `PageView` in screen.